# How to strip every character from a string except numeric characters and decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

'US $109.90/ea' should become '109.90'

Comment: Replace `[^\d.]+` with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all characters except *number* and *dot* with empty string:

```js
var str = 'US $109.90/ea';
var number = str.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '');
console.log(number);
```

Comment: No alternation needed. Add `+` quantifier to make it more efficient (like I have in my comment below the question)